Flutter windows 125% scaling issue
In flutter I have created widgets based on the width of the screen to make it responsive, but the default 125% scaling is kind of messing with my flutter ui.

This is at 100 percent scaling

This is at 125% scaling
Althought in these images the ui is not getting that much distorted but in more complex ui, on which i am currently working on is getting distorted as there are images and textboxes and containers which getting scaled up and giving the effect of zoom which is not looking good for it.
I have tested my same ui at tablets, that is also showing fine as the tablet is showing at 100% scaling and my code is handling that pretty well
Now what I have tried
I have tried to use scaled app and fitted box to scale down the app but the common issue with them is they are not working with stack layout.
Is there any way to fix this?

I will use Wrap with Chip/Custom widget
